# MB Air: connect, update App Store with broken Wifi/Airport via USB WiFi

Tags: macbook-pro, wifi, usb, mac-appstore, airport

On my MB Air 2,1 (mid 2009) the wifi is broken. Connecting with the internet is possible via an Apple USB-Ethernet-adapter.

When trying to install an app/update via the App Store (e.g. to OSx El Capitan) the message in App Store is:

> Your device or computer could not be verified.

It seems to me a working Wifi Airport Card is a prerequisite for connecting/authenticating with the App Store.

1. Can anyone confirm this is the issue?
2. Is a work around available?

Otherwise I've googled a bit and as far as I can tell the options for this 6 year old machine are either to have the wifi repaired (€125) or buy a USB wifi dongle (€22) and accept that OSx will not be able to update.

Cf. e.g. this post:

> A NIC (network interface card) is needed for authentication purposes to make sure the computer is what it claims to be.

on [forums.macrumors.com](http://forums.macrumors.com/threads/macbook-air-removed-airport-card-problems.1723989/#post-18975285) reads like a sound argument.

Answer (score 1):

repair wifi card or logic board then You will can log in usb wifi dongle or ethernet cable won't work. I know this is ridiculous.